# how to I can use delegate in Javascript

Tags: javascript, delegates

I have a constructor like that

```
function TodoController() {
  this.todoList = [];
  this.id = 0;
  this.ENTER_KEY = 13;
};

TodoController.prototype = {

  todoView: function (todo) {
    var controller =  todoController.todoList;
    console.log('controller', controller);

    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.setAttribute('class', 'todoItem');

    var inpCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
    this.setAttributes(inpCheckbox, { 'type': 'checkbox', 'class' : 'itemList'} );

    var lbContent = document.createElement('label');
    lbContent.innerHTML = todo.getContent();

    var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
    console.log('id', this.id)
    this.setAttributes(btnRemove, { 'class': 'remove', 'id' : this.id} );
    // btnRemove.setAttribute('id', this.id);

    //item append each element
    item.appendChild(inpCheckbox);
    item.appendChild(lbContent);
    item.appendChild(btnRemove);

    console.log('item', item);

    //ul append each item
    document.querySelector('#todoListView').appendChild(item);
  },
```

now I want to create a event to delete the item, it like that

```
var deleteItem = document.getElementsByClassName('remove')
    for(var i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
      deleteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('done')
      });
    }
```

My problem is I can call the class `remove`, because it to be create into `todoView` function. In the jQuery I saw it use delegate method, but I don't know how to use it with javascript. please help me

Comment: Delegation is just technique that takes advantage of the fact that events bubble. It can be implemented in plain JS as well, but it's a bit tricky and requires an event handler attached to a static parent element, and then a filter to see what target triggered the event etc.

Comment: so for the this case, how I can call the `.remove` class, because it not create, when the time I write these function

Comment: You have to add the event handler to `#todoListView` and then filter the `event.target` for the class `.delete`

Comment: I'm not clear about your answer. For now I create a Todo List app, now I want to delete each `li` from `ul` `#todoListView`, but class `remove` not exits on the html file now. it just have when I create new a `li`. but for this case I can't call the `.remove` class

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/21mnbzm6/

Comment: It correct, thank you so much